# The glibc versions of the container and the host are different，will influence performance？

Tags: performance, ceph

When the glibc version of the host and the container version are inconsistent, the storage service performance is very low compared to the glic version, Is this problem related to glibc?（I use ceph ） I read on the Internet that some people said it is related to the GLIC version, but there is not enough evidence to prove it. Is there any way to verify whether the container and host have saem glic version will affect the performance?

this is my  glic version

```
[root@node52 ~]# ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.28
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
[root@node52 ~]# docker exec -it 1f5fbfa7924b bash ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

i need some ideas to solve this problem